# Trouble understanding Banach-Tarski paradox proof on wikipedia

Tags: paradoxes

When I read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox#A_sketch_of_the_proof I do not understand this part of the proof:

$$F_2 = \{e\}\cup S(a) \cup S(a^{-1}) \cup S(b) \cup S(b^{-1}) =aS(a^{-1})\cup S(a)$$

where S(a) is the set of all non-forbidden strings starting with a. If I understood it right it has to be a finite string, i.e. the longest allowed string is of length $n\in \mathbb{N}$. If you write the length of the longest allowed string as a superscript, does this actually say

$$
F_2 = \{e\}\cup S^n(a) \cup S^n(a^{-1}) \cup S^n(b) \cup S^n(b^{-1}) =aS^{n+1}(a^{-1})\cup S^{n}(a), n\in\mathbb{N}
$$
? Because otherwise I cannot see how the equality can work.

Comment: All strings are finite, but there are strings of arbitrary length

Answer (score 2):

$S(a)$, for example, is the set of all finite-length non-forbidden strings which begin with $a$.  $S(a)=\{a,aa,ab,ab^{-1},aaa,aab,aab^{-1},aba,aba^{-1},abb,ab^{-1}a,ab^{-1}a^{-1},ab^{-1}b^{-1},\cdots\}$.  There is no upper bound on the lengths of strings in $S(a)$, but the length of any particular string is finite.

The decomposition of $F_2$ is saying that every non-forbidden string is either the identity, a string beginning with $a$, with $a^{-1}$, with $b$, or with $b^{-1}$.  (The Cayley graph of $F_2$ in the Wikipedia article is a useful illustration for this decomposition.)

Comment: So, the cardinality of S(a) is countably infinite?

Comment: (If it is I'm not that surprised it is a paradox, playing with infinites seems to be the go to way to end up with weird results :-) )

Comment: @Emil:  Yes, the cardinality of $S(a)$ is countably infinite.  Your equation at the bottom is correct if you delete the $F_2=$ or make it $F_2^n=$.  The equality doesn't work for strings of limited to length $n$ as the $n+1$ subscript on the right shows, but it does work when the length is unlimited.  [Wagon's book](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Banach_Tarski_Paradox.html?id=_HveugDvaQMC) on the subject is excellent.